# Why doesn't a simple CSS to HTML link work for me in visual studio code with live server? But normally it works on other pages like css runner

Tags: html, css

```
body{
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Calculadora</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <script src="./script.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't a simple CSS to HTML link work for me in visual studio code with live server?
But normally it works on other pages like css runner

This show me the browser with Live Server
[image: This is my browser with Live Server]
This show me the CSS Runner
[image: Test with CSS Runner]

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the development console?  On the network tab of those tools, is a request made for the CSS file?  What is the server's response?

Comment: [Force refresh](https://www.minitool.com/news/f5-vs-ctrl-f5.html), which in Chrome is Cntrl-F5. That will reload the page and not use the cached version of it. If that doesn't work, check F12 Developer Tools -> Network tab to verify the css file is being loaded successfully

Comment: responds correctly to the CSS file request

Comment: Possibly it is a live server configuration in CSS?

Comment: @MiguelÁngel: By "responds correctly" do you mean that, in the Network tab of the browser's debugging tools, you can observe the body of the response for the CSS file and it contains *exactly* and *only* the CSS code shown at the beginning of the question?  In those same tools, in the DOM explorer, when you examind the `<body>` element, what styles are applied to it?

Comment: It returns this status but I don't know if that's what you're referring to.

```Request URL:
http://192.168.98.1:5500/style.css
Application Method:
GET
Status Code:
200 OK
Remote Address:
192.168.98.1:5500```

Comment: @MiguelÁngel: All that means is that the server responded successfully.  Click on the request/response and observe the body/content of the response itself.  What does it contain?

Comment: Nothing, in fact in the view it looks the same as the page

Comment: Maybe the problem is the ```link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">```  This is the first thing I checked

Comment: @MiguelÁngel: If *nothing* (an empty content/body) is returned for the request to `style.css` then that's what the server returned.  Are you sure you're looking at the right CSS file in your code?  Are you sure that file was saved?  Have you tried a forced refresh in your browser?  Cleared the browser cache?  At this point all anybody here can do is guess.  The code shown has no obvious problems, it's likely something wrong in your overall setup.

Comment: What do you mean by forced update? I just tried Ctrl + f5 to clear the cache and nothing

Comment: @MiguelÁngel: Can you replicate the problem in any hosted environment (even something as simple as Github Pages) so we can observe it as well?  It's still highly likely that the problem is some oversight in your overall setup that isn't included in the question here.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, I was busy. I don't know how to use github pages, a brief introduction?